# Android Preference like Android 6 native Settings

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences, preferencescreen

How can I achieve this? I've been searching and found nothing.

[image]

Is it using 'com.android.support:preference-v7:+'?

Comment: You don't have to use the support library https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Comment: The thing is I've done it with that library, but it doesn't has this look. I have this http://imgur.com/a/u0s7e and i want to get the look of the screen settings above, with the divider shorter and separated in "cards".

Comment: Yeah, I know that has been asked many times here, but I haven't been able to determine how that divider is created without some RecyclerView of PreferenceFragments within a CardView

Comment: Hm ill try that, didn't thought on that. Thank you.